# how to return user to the former question

Tags: c#

so as stated iam a total newbie beginner at programming, iam starting off my practising with making a little quizz program.

Iam trying to return people to the same question if they answered wrong. ive tried putting it all in a while loop and making the while loop run untill the correct answer is done. but when i do while loops i cannot point at my "ask" variabel that contains the user input. if this makes sense i hope you can help :)

heres my code:

```
using System;

namespace Quiz1
{
    class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Reads from the command prompt and attempts to convert into an integer.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Returns the converted integer value read from the command prompt, or zero if unsuccessful.</returns>
        /// 
        private static int ReadNumber()
        {
            string text = Console.ReadLine();

            if (int.TryParse(text, out int voresTal) == true)
            {
                return voresTal;
            }

            return 0;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Requests the user to enter their age, using minAge and maxAge as lower and upper age limits.
        /// If incorrect input is detected, proper feedback is provided to the user.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="minAge">The minimum acceptable age.</param>
        /// <param name="maxAge">The maximum acceptable age.</param>
        /// <returns>Returns a valid age within rage of minAge and maxAge, as an integer value.</returns>
        private static int ReadAge(int minAge, int maxAge)
        {
            int age = minAge - 1;

            while (age < minAge || age > maxAge)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Indtast din Alder.");

                age = ReadNumber();

                if (age == 0)
                {
                    //Giver brugeren besked om at han fejlede.
                    Console.WriteLine("Input a Valid Age between 5-120");
                }
                else if (age < minAge || age > maxAge)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Impossible for you to be: " + age + " old ");
                }
            }

            return age;
        }

        private static int AskQuestion(string question, string[] answers)
        {
            int choice = -1;

            while (choice == -1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(question);

                for (int i = 0; i < answers.Length; i++)
                {
                    int choiceNumber = i + 1;

                    Console.WriteLine(choiceNumber + ": " + answers[i]);
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Your Choice: ");

                int input = ReadNumber();

                if (input >= 1 && input <= answers.Length)
                {
                    choice = input - 1;
                }

            }

            return choice;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the Allround quiz for your enjoyment!");
            Console.WriteLine("Lets start by knowing your age to determine the Difficulty");

            int age = ReadAge(5, 120);

            Console.WriteLine("You are: " + age + "old");
            Console.WriteLine("Thank you, i now know your age and will determine the Difficulty. Good luck !");

            if (age <= 16)
            {

                        string[] answers = new string[]
                                        {
                                            "yes",
                                            "no",
                                            "none of the above"
                                        };

                        int theRightAnswer = 0;

                        int ask = AskQuestion(
                            "Is the earth round or flat ?",
                            answers
                            );

                        Console.WriteLine("Your answer: " + answers[ask]);

                        if (ask == theRightAnswer)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Congratz your correct!");
                        }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure were the problem is, in ReadAge there should be no problem with accessing the age.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to simply modify the AskQuestion method to not allow user to exit before giving the right answer, like this:

```
  private static int AskQuestion(string question, string[] answers, int right)
        {
            int choice = -1;
            
            bool isRight = false;

            while (!isRight)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(question);

                for (int i = 0; i < answers.Length; i++)
                {
                    int choiceNumber = i + 1;

                    Console.WriteLine(choiceNumber + ": " + answers[i]);
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Your Choice: ");

                int input = ReadNumber();

                if (input >= 1 && input <= answers.Length)
                {
                    choice = input - 1;
                }
                
                 Console.WriteLine("Your answer: " + answers[choice]);

                if (choice == right)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Congratz your correct!");
                    isRight = true;
                } else{
                    Console.WriteLine("Try again!");
                }

            }

            return choice;
        }
```

And then call the methood like this:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the Allround quiz for your enjoyment!");
            Console.WriteLine("Lets start by knowing your age to determine the Difficulty");

            int age = ReadAge(5, 120);

            Console.WriteLine("You are: " + age + "old");
            Console.WriteLine("Thank you, i now know your age and will determine the Difficulty. Good luck !");

            if (age <= 16)
            {

                        string[] answers = new string[]
                                        {
                                            "yes",
                                            "no",
                                            "none of the above"
                                        };

                        int theRightAnswer = 0;

                        AskQuestion(
                            "Is the earth round or flat ?",
                            answers,
                            theRightAnswer
                            );

                       

            }
        }
```

Comment: If you go to this approach, make sure to rename the function from **AskQuestion**, to **AskQuestionUntilCorrect**, as it is a good practice that you function names describe in the best way what the function does.

Comment: Also, you will not need a return from the new *AskQuestionUntilCorrect* function, as it will only returns when you make it correct, maybe you instead return the amount of attempts before correct?

Answer (score 0):

This is not what your while loop is doing:

Your while loop will stop at the moment the user gives a input that is between 1 and 3 ( the length of your answers array.)

it means your while loop will execute again only if the user gives a input like 5 or 0.

But you're almost there.
If you want your QUIZ to repeat the answer just modify your main function to something like

```cs
int theRightAnswer = 0;
int ask;

do {
    ask = AskQuestion(
    "Is the earth round or flat ?",
    answers
    );
    Console.WriteLine("Your answer: " + answers[ask]);
    
    if (ask == theRightAnswer)
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Congratz your correct!");
    }
    else 
       Console.WriteLine("try again");
} while(ask != theRightAnswer);
```